# Is extern "C" no longer needed anymore in cuda?

Tags: cuda

I heard from someone that  nvcc defaults to C++ for host code ,so extern "C" is no longer needed any more, unless the rest of host code is in C,is that true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, the word "anymore" is a bit confusing. I don't think that anything has changed there, and Robert Crovella pointed out the main difference between using and not `extern "C"` in his answer in a technical sense.

However, I'd like to point out an important difference that is implied by using `extern "C"` for a CUDA kernel, which might be one of the reasons for the confusion:

When using the CUDA driver API, it is possible to load a "CUDA module" and a "CUDA function" manually. Now imagine a .CU file containing a kernel like this:

```
__global__ void exampleKernel(float** data) { ... }
```

This can be compiled with the NVCC, to yield a CUBIN (CUDA binary) or PTX file. After loading this file as a "CUDA module" module, one can access the function (namely, the CUDA kernel):

```
cuModuleLoad(&cuModule, modulePath);
cuModuleGetFunction(&cuFunction, cuModule, "exampleKernel");
```

The second call will most likely not succeed: The name of the kernel, `exampleKernel`, will most likely *mangled*, because it is considered as a C++ function (seee [Name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B)).

When the kernel is declared as `extern "C"`, as in this example:

```
extern "C" 
__global__ void exampleKernel(float** data) { ... }
```

then **no** name mangling takes place, and the function can be accessed with

```
cuModuleGetFunction(&cuFunction, cuModule, "exampleKernel");
```

as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its true that nvcc by default assumes a c++ linkage style. I'm not sure what you mean by "anymore". I think it has been this way a long time.

As with any other C/C++ code mix, you can use

```
extern "C" {}
```

constructs to indicate C-style external linkage instead.

Comment: Is there a way to request that `.cu` files be compiled as C files so that vandalizing every function prototype with `extern "C"` is unnecessary?

Comment: @Nick, you don't have to vanadlize every function. Just wrap all of them inside `extern "C" { [all of them go here] }`.